# Water leaking under car

Tags: audi, water-leak

Today i found a puddle under my Audi a4 avant 2002. It looks like water(no smell and no color). On internet i found out that this happens mostly because ac condensate but all cases are describing cooling down cars during hot summer days. In my case its like 3-5 celsius outside, i tried to turn the ac off and went for a short drive but the water still comes out from some small hole(dont know name for this look at pictures). It is placed under front passanger side. 
Is this normal or should i go to mehanic?

[[image: leaking hole]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I can see things are wet in the picture, but I really cannot get a perspective of the size or where you're talking about. I'd suggest it still could be draining from the HVAC drain, but couldn't be sure.

Comment: If you have been running the defrost, it is likely that the car was also running the AC compressor. That would condense humidity even though it's cold out. Good job being aware of the state of your car!